# Extracting marginal PDF in Python

Tags: numpy, jupyter

I have a simple question that I can't find an answer for. 
The sample is drawn from a bivariate normal distribution (X,Y) with given parameters like this:

```
import numpy as np
sample = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 1], [[1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.8]], 10000)
```

Now I need to extract marginal distributions from this joint distribution. I want to get two arrays, called fx_x and fy_y that contain marginal distributions from X and Y.

```
fx_x = [....]
fy_y = [....]
```

How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want samples from the marginals?  Since the mean and covariance appear to be known, why not do `fx = np.random.normal(1, 1)` and `fy = np.random.normal(1, 0.8)` ?  Or do you want to assume you only have access to the joint samples?

Answer (score 1):

You could first compute the two-dimensional histogram using, for instance, `np.histogram2d`. Then integrate it over each axis with some numerical method such as `scipy.integrate.simpson` in order to get marginal distributions.

For your particular example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simpson
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


np.random.seed(0)
mean, cov = [1, 5], [[1, .2], [.2, .5]] 
z = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 100_000)

fz, ex, ey = np.histogram2d(*z.T, bins=50, density=True)
x = (ex[:-1] + ex[1:]) / 2
y = (ey[:-1] + ey[1:]) / 2

fx = simpson(fz, y, axis=1)
fy = simpson(fz, x, axis=0)


gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[3,1], height_ratios=[1,3])
ax_fz = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
ax_fx = plt.subplot(gs[0,0], sharex=ax_fz)
ax_fy = plt.subplot(gs[1,1], sharey=ax_fz)

ax_fz.pcolormesh(x, y, fz.T)
ax_fx.bar(x, fx)
ax_fy.barh(y, fy)

plt.show()
```

[image]